# What is this branch of mathematics?

Tags: solid-geometry, packing-problem

What is the branch and topic of mathematics concerned with volume optimization of objects that can be morphed/manipulated?
I.e. **finding the most efficient way to position 3D objects**, *where each object can be morphed under certain conditions*, **inside an enclosed volume?**

**Ex:** You are bagging apples in identical bags. Each bag must have 4 apples (4 apples is also the maximum any bag can hold). The bags are morph-able to 'some extent', but you can't have the 4 apples in a straight line inside a bag, for example. You place the apple bags inside of a box. **What is the most efficient way to do this so you can have the highest number of apples that is physically possible inside one box.** (This can get tricky because bags in the box won't necessarily fit together in the ideal ways.)

Comment: I would call this a kind of [packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems).  There is [a tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/packing-problem)

Comment: @henry The thing here is that the containers can be morphed. In packing problems, they are well-defined. I figured this maybe fell more into some topology topic.

Comment: Typical "morphs" in topology would alter the shape of the bag much more than you allow. I think a better way to view the bag is as a set of constraints on the relative positions of the apples inside it. Then you have to pack the apples in the box under the constraints imposed by the bags.

Comment: That's a good idea. But the constraints can always be altered, in that case. Hmmm..
Edit: I get what you are saying now.

Comment: This would probably be called optimization because you want “the most efficient”.

Comment: I would classify this as a discrete geometry problem; I'd imagine depending on the constraints different problems will admit different techniques.